# Reading Text files with multi-processing in Python

Tags: python

I'm scanning several thousand text files and creating a python class object for each file, storing the file's contents after performing some parsing methods, on the class object. Is it possible to do this with multi-threading and have a final variable containing a list of all the python objects? Assuming this would be the best approach how would I do this?

I'm open to any solution whether it's multi-threading or multi-processing. Currently doing one file at a time in order seems quite slow.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Process:

1. Loop through directory of files
2. Read each files contents and perform some parsing operations
3. Store the files contents on a python class object per file
4. Append class object to list

Code:

```
import os
import sys

root = "C:/Users/jmartini/Desktop/Temp/text_files"


class fileObject(object):
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self._content = ''
        self._filepath = ''
        self.filepath = filepath


    @property
    def filepath(self):
        return self._filepath


    @filepath.setter
    def filepath(self, value):
        self._filepath = value

        # instantiate
        if os.path.isfile(value):
            self._content = ''
            with open(value, 'r') as f:
                self._content = f.read()
                # After reading content i need to do more parsing tasks


    @property
    def content(self):
        return self._content


def collect_files(directory):
    objs = []
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            if not os.path.splitext(filename)[-1] in ['.sbs']:
                continue
            objs.append(fileObject(os.path.join(root, filename)))
    return objs


objs = collect_files(root)
print len(objs)
# for o in objs:
#     print o.content
```

Comment: Why do you think multithreading will help?

Comment: Well I'm open to any suggestion. It just appears quite slow to do this one file at a time.